# WooCommerce checkout message based on specific product category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product

Wordpress store is using WooCommerce, and I have a small purchase note that I need to **appear on WooCommerce Checkout**, but only when a certain product is being purchased.

I have added a custom message that now appears below the Place Order button.
However its showing up no matter what is in the cart.

This is the code I currently have in place:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'allclean_add_checkout_content', 12 );
function allclean_add_checkout_content() {
echo '<div class="checkoutdisc">Custom message appears here fine.</div>';
}
```

Is there a simple code that I can add before this line, that makes it **only apply when a certain category** product is in the cart?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Here we check that we have a product item in cart with **this special category**. If the condition is matched (in one of the items of the cart), the message is displayed.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'allclean_add_checkout_content', 12 );
function allclean_add_checkout_content() {
    // set your special category name, slug or ID here:
    $special_cat = 'special_category';
    $bool = false;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $item = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( has_term( $special_cat, 'product_cat', $item->id ) )
            $bool = true;
    }
    // If the special cat is detected in one items of the cart
    // It displays the message
    if ($bool)
        echo '<div class="checkoutdisc">This is Your custom message displayed.</div>';
}
```

> You can also use **an array of products Ids** instead of a product category...

In this case the code will be a little bit different:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'allclean_add_checkout_content', 12 );
function allclean_add_checkout_content() {
    // set your products IDs here:
    $product_ids = array( 31, 68, 87, 124);
    $bool = false;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $item = $cart_item['data'];
        if ( in_array( $item->id, $product_ids ) )
            $bool = true;
    }
    // If the special cat is detected in one items of the cart
    // It displays the message
    if ($bool)
        echo '<div class="checkoutdisc">This is Your custom message displayed.</div>';
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file*.

**This code is tested and works.**

Comment: How to use it for a variable product and a specific variable?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check the cart contents.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'allclean_add_checkout_content', 12 );
function allclean_add_checkout_content() {
    $cart = WC()->cart;
    foreach ( $this->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];

        if ( has_term( 'special-category', 'product_cat', $_product->id ) ){
            echo '<div class="checkoutdisc">Your custom message.</div>';
        }
    }
}
```